# Быстрый алгоритм поиска индекса начала пересечения двух массивов (предоптимизашки)

Tags: javascript, массивы

Возникла задачка добавления новых элементов в стек представленный js-массивом.
Сложность в том что массив с новыми элементами всегда частично пересекается со стеком (то есть, всегда содержит в начале реально новые элементы, а затем следуют "старые" которые надо проигнорировать).
При этом, сами значения могут как угодно дублироваться. То есть, пересечений может быть и несколько, но истинным мы считаем только последнее: максимально длинную последовательность элементов в конце массива новых значений, совпадающую с последовательностью значений на верхушке стека. Далее на примере это будет понятнее.
Значения в данных только числовые, их тип всегда `number`.

Пример стека (тут я сократил его до 15ти элементов, а по факту их сотни):

```js
[1.52, 1.42, 1.61, 1.42, 1.03, 1.22, 1.59, 0, 2.71, 5.65, 1.18, 1.67, 4.44, 4.65, 1.73]
```

Пример массива новых элементов (их кол-во всегда ≥10, но значительно меньше чем в стеке):

```js
[8.04, 1.52, 0, 1.17, 1.37, 1.52, 1.42, 1.61, 1.42, 1.03]
```

Здесь новые элементы это только первые пять значений (`8.04`, `1.52`, `0`, `1.17`, `1.37`), а далее начинается пересечение с верхними элементами стека. Это пересечение тут состоит из элементов `1.52`, `1.42`, `1.61`, `1.42`, `1.03`.
Новых элементов не всегда именно 5, но всегда есть как минимум один.

---

Я решил задачу "в лоб" и не очень эффективно, следующим алгоритмом: последовательно перебирая новые элементы в прямом порядке, сравниваю последующие значения со значениями в стеке (проходом вниз, во вложенном цикле) пока выполняется равенство значений и элементы массива не закончились. Таким образом, результатом является индекс того элемента в массиве "новых", начиная с которого равенство значений сохраняется до конца массива.
Код решения:

```js
// решение, которое не нравится
const findIntersection = (stack, newValues) => {
  const newValuesLen = newValues.length;          // слегка экономим такты запомнив длину массива новых элементов в константе
  return newValues.findIndex((_, idx) => {        // результатом хотим индекс, c которого начинается пересечение
    let isIntersection = true;                    // инициализируем истиной просто для того чтобы соблюсти условие на первой итерации
    // последовательное сравнение элементов стека с новыми, пока соблюдается их равенство
    for (let i = idx, j = 0; isIntersection && (i < newValuesLen); ++i, ++j)
      isIntersection = newValues[i] === stack[j];
    return isIntersection;
  });
};


// проверка
const stack = [1.52, 1.42, 1.61, 1.42, 1.03, 1.22, 1.59, 0, 2.71, 5.65, 1.18, 1.67, 4.44, 4.65, 1.73];
const newValues = [8.04, 1.52, 0, 1.17, 1.37, 1.52, 1.42, 1.61, 1.42, 1.03];

const endIdx = findIntersection(stack, newValues);
stack.unshift(...newValues.slice(0, endIdx > -1 ? endIdx : Infinity));    // добавляем на вершину стека новые элементы (срез до начала пересечения)

console.log(stack);    //  [8.04, 1.52, 0, 1.17, 1.37, 1.52, 1.42, 1.61, 1.42, 1.03, 1.22, 1.59, 0, 2.71, 5.65, 1.18, 1.67, 4.44, 4.65, 1.73]
                       //    ^ добавленные элементы     ^ начало "старых" элементов
```

Этот код пока что не тормозит (фактической проблемы нет), но мне хотелось бы узнать как в целом лучше подходить к решению такой задачи - найти более быстрый алгоритм просто "на будущее", разобраться в его логике решения и научиться чему-то новому.

Соответственно, вопрос: каким способом можно побыстрее/поэффективнее выполнить ту же самую операцию поиска начала пересечения элементов массивов? :)

Comment: а недостаточно просто в маленьком массиве найти индекс первого элемента в стеке?

Comment: @Grundy, значения в стеке (и массиве с новыми элементами) вполне могут повторяться, а значит получается что одного совпадения будет недостаточно для определения индекса пересечения((

Comment: не понял тогда.

Comment: @Grundy, ну решаемая задача заключается в определении индекса элемента меньшего массива, с которого начинается пересечение с большим массивом (пересечение - это последовательность элементов, одинаковая в обоих массивах. Здесь в примере пересечением является последовательность `1.52, 1.42, 1.61, 1.42, 1.03`). Если искать в малом массиве первый элемент большого - возможны ошибки из-за дублирующихся значений (так что приходится искать именно последовательность). _// Я отредактировал вопрос, теперь элемент `1.42` повторяется._

Comment: пересечение всегда начинается с первого элемента стека?

Comment: @Grundy, да, всегда с первого.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130796/discussion-between-grundy-and-yar85).

Comment: Ради эксперимента попробовал в обратном направление, [результат один и тот же](https://jsben.ch/Q7zng)

Answer (score 2):

Рассчитываете для имеющегося массива [префикс-функцию](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/prefix_function)

Затем при добавлении нового куска дополняете массив префикс-функции. Если в добавленной части есть большие значения (в вашем примере это 5), то нашли хвост, совпадающий с головой.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю сначала получить контрольную сумму предполагаемых участков пересечения. Для `newValues` это сумма всех значений кроме первого, который по условию обязательно будет уникальным. Для `stack` это сумма значений на ту же длину.

Далее в цикле сравниваем полученные суммы, вычитая каждый раз из stack_sum последний элемент из предыдущего диапазона, а из values_sum вычитаем первый элемент. И так пока максимально совпадающий диапазон не будет найден. Или возвращаем 0 если совпадений не найдено (так как `newValues[0]` точно не будет совпадением).

Таким образом, полная проверка на совпадение делается только при совпадении сумм значений соответствующих диапазонов. При этом расчет суммы перебором делается только однажды для максимального диапазона каждого массива, а затем вычитаются последнее и первое значение соответственно уже по индексу.

Учитывая, что операции производятся с дробными числами проверка на равенство `Math.abs(stack_sum - values_sum) < 0.01`, компенсируя тем самым возможные погрешности округления, что можно избежать переведя все числа в целые. Работа с целыми числами будет быстрее и надежнее, а проверка проще: `stack_sum === value_sum`.

Если данные поступают в виде строки, то контрольную сумму можно получить складывая коды символов, например, или каким-нибудь другим хитрым способом.

```js
const stack = [1.52, 1.42, 1.61, 1.42, 1.03, 1.22, 1.59, 0, 2.71, 5.65, 1.18, 1.67, 4.44, 4.65, 1.73];
const newValues = [8.04, 1.52, 0, 1.17, 1.37, 1.52, 1.42, 1.61, 1.42, 1.03];

addNewValues(stack,newValues);

console.log(stack);



function partialSum(array, firstIndex, num){
    let result = 0;
    for ( let i = 0; i < num; i++ ) {
        result += array[firstIndex + i];
    }
    return result;
}

function isIntersection(stack, newValues, fromIndex){
    for (let i = 0; i < newValues.length - fromIndex; i++){
        if(newValues[fromIndex + i] !== stack[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function findIntersection(stack, newValues) {
    const min_num = 1;
    const initial_size = newValues.length - min_num;
    
    let stack_sum = partialSum(stack, 0, initial_size);
    let values_sum = partialSum(newValues, 1, initial_size);
    
    for( let i = min_num; i < initial_size; i++){
        if(Math.abs(stack_sum - values_sum) < 0.01){  // Проверка для дробных чисел
            if (isIntersection(stack, newValues, i)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        stack_sum -= stack[initial_size - i];
        values_sum -= newValues[i];
    }
    
    return 0;
}

function addNewValues(stack, newValues){
    const endIdx = findIntersection(stack, newValues);
    stack.unshift(...newValues.slice( 0, endIdx ? endIdx : newValues.length));
}
```